# how to use post method using json for android

Tags: javascript, java, android

how to use post method using json for android`enter code here`public class HttpHandler {
    private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

```
public HttpHandler() {
}


public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
    String response=null;

    try
    {
        URL url=new URL(reqUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        InputStream inputStream=new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        response=convertStreamToString(inputStream);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return response ;
}
private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: this is not related to javascript

Comment: I strongly recommend you [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) as communication library. You just need java objects that can be converted to json.

Comment: "using json for android"... I dont undestand, json is a format. Many android apps are done in java, others in xamarin. Are you getting any error? what is the content returned to yor GET request?